# Spring Cache not works

Tags: java, spring-cache

I caching project with `Spring Cache`.
First, I added annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MultiSelectJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableCaching    //Spring Cache
public class Application {
```

Second, I created bean:

```
@Bean("authCacheManager")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager() {
        @Override
        protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(String name) {
            return new ConcurrentMapCache(
                    name,
                    CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).build().asMap(),
                    false
            );
        }
    };
}
```

I set cache expiration time (1 day).
Than, I added annotation behind method I need to cache:

```
@Cacheable(value = "ldap", key = "#username")
public Authentication authenticateByLdap(String username, String password, User userDetails) {
```

As I understand, when I try to authenticate with matches param `username`, method must to return cached data without enter it. But app enter method (I see it in logs).

What's wrong?